# Adding multiple contacts to Android

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Probably answer is trivial but I can't figure it out. I'm trying to add contacts with piece of code below, but only "contact_0" exists in contacts list. Do you know what is wrong with this code?

```
 public void myMethod(){

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> ops = new ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation>();
        ops.add(ContentProviderOperation
                .newInsert(ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTENT_URI)
                .withValue(ContactsContract.RawContacts.ACCOUNT_TYPE,
                        null)
                .withValue(ContactsContract.RawContacts.ACCOUNT_NAME,
                        null)
                .withValue(ContactsContract.RawContacts.AGGREGATION_MODE,
                        ContactsContract.RawContacts.AGGREGATION_MODE_DISABLED).build());

        // ------------------------------------------------------ Name

        ops.add(ContentProviderOperation
                .newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
                .withValueBackReference(
                        ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, i)
                .withValue(
                        ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE,
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
                .withValue(
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.DISPLAY_NAME,
                        "contact_"+i).build());

        // ------------------------------------------------------ Work
        // Number

        ops.add(ContentProviderOperation
                .newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
                .withValueBackReference(
                        ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, i)
                .withValue(
                        ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE,
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
                .withValue(
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER,
                        "01 62384")
                .withValue(
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE,
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_WORK)
                .build());



        try {
            getContentResolver().applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, ops);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Any ideas guys?

Thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 0):

```
public void myMethod(){

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> ops = new ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation>();
        ops.add(ContentProviderOperation
                .newInsert(ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTENT_URI)
                .withValue(ContactsContract.RawContacts.ACCOUNT_TYPE,
                        null)
                .withValue(ContactsContract.RawContacts.ACCOUNT_NAME,
                        null)
                .withValue(ContactsContract.RawContacts.AGGREGATION_MODE,
                        ContactsContract.RawContacts.AGGREGATION_MODE_DISABLED).build());

        // ------------------------------------------------------ Name

        ops.add(ContentProviderOperation
                .newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
                .withValueBackReference(
                        ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, 0)
                .withValue(
                        ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE,
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
                .withValue(
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.DISPLAY_NAME,
                        "contact_"+i).build());

        // ------------------------------------------------------ Work
        // Number

        ops.add(ContentProviderOperation
                .newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
                .withValueBackReference(
                        ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, 0)
                .withValue(
                        ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE,
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
                .withValue(
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER,
                        "01 62384")
                .withValue(
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE,
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_WORK)
                .build());



        try {
            getContentResolver().applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, ops);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

please use RAW_CONTACT_ID 0 in every insert operation. This works for me.